# ms access sql: concatenate query with a crostab subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Query in current form:

```
SELECT
  sr,
  Iif([1]="Null", "", "; 1: "&[1])
& Iif([2]="Null", "", "; 2: "&[2])
& Iif([3]="Null", "", "; 3: "&[3]) AS all_parameters
from (
TRANSFORM first([value])
SELECT [id]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [id]
PIVOT [value]);
```

1) I have a table with many to one relationship.

```
[id] | [values] 
   1 |  v1
   1 |  v2 
   2 |  v1
   2 |  v3
```

That I want to look like:

```
1 | v1, v2
2 | v1, v3
```

2) I started with a cross tab query:

```
TRANSFORM first([value])
SELECT [id]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [id]
PIVOT [value];
```

It returns a display like this:

```
[id] | [v1] | [v2] | [v3]
 1   |   1  |   2  |
 2   |   1  |      |   3
```

It returns just numbers because the values came from a drop down select menu.

3) I want to concatenate the v1, v2, and v3 values together while dropping the Nulls so I'm using this: [MS Access - combine non-null column values into a (column name: column value) text string / field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589086/ms-access-combine-non-null-column-values-into-a-column-name-column-value-te)

To create this:

```
SELECT
  sr,
  Iif([1] is null, "", "; 1: "&[1])
& Iif([2] is null, "", "; 2: "&[2])
& Iif([3] is null, "", "; 3: "&[3]) AS all_parameters
from (
TRANSFORM first([value])
SELECT [id]
FROM [table]
GROUP BY [id]
PIVOT [value]);
```

4) When I run it i get a syntax error highlighting TRANSFORM.

How do I fix this and how can I get the drop down references to display?

EDIT___________________

So now I have:

```
  SELECT
    [ID],
    Iif([1] is null, "", "; 1: "&[1])
  & Iif([2] is null, "", "; 2: "&[2])
  & Iif([3] is null, "", "; 3: "&[3]) AS all_parameters
  from [query]
```

It returns:

```
[id] | [all_parameters] 
 1   |   ;1: ; 2:  |  
 2   |   ;1: ; 3:  |
```

Comment: Your "Query In current form" is exactly the same as the query in Step 4) that returns the syntax error. Is this intentional?

Comment: @kismert Yes. I wanted to lay it out like that before showing the steps it took to get there. Kinda like showing a picture of a finished bed before show pics of the build process.

Comment: When you say `IIf([1]="Null"`, do you mean to compare to the string `"Null"`, or the value `Null`? If the latter, use `IIf([1] Is Null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do that. Try saving the Crosstab query as a named query, and use that as the source of your parent query.

See:

- https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/crosstab-query-as-a-subquery-how-to-do-that.1176819/
- https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=186465

Comment: Yup, though you should get rid of the _probably_. A crosstab query is special in Access SQL, and comes with several limitations, such as the fact that it can't be used as a subquery.